# Ruby keeps telling me my file does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-exists

I'm trying to check if a file exists with RoR but it keeps saying this file does not exist and I can't understand why.

```
if File.exist?('~/Desktop/test.xls')
  p 'File EXISTS'
else
  p 'Cannot find any file'
end
```

Of course the file exists and I can access it with the terminal using 'ls'.

The script is into the scripts folder of my rails app.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Have you tried replacing the `~` with your actual home directory?

Comment: Yes, thanks it just worked ! by any chance, would you know, then how I could share this code with non-programmers? I was hoping anyone could access the file with just one button but if I code my own name instead of '~' it won't be possible, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
if File.exist?("#{Dir.home}/Desktop/test.xls")
  p 'File EXISTS'
else
  p 'Cannot find any file'
end
```

where `Dir.home` is your particular home directory (in my case it is `/Users/m.pontyushenko/`)

Comment: it works, thanks a lot ! 
by any chance, would you know, then how I could share this code with non-programmers? I was hoping anyone could access the file with just one button but if I code my own name instead of '~' it won't be possible, right?

Comment: @El-Cortez you mean you want to check if a person has particular file on their computer?

Comment: @El-Cortez I made an update to my answer. Just check it.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much! You just saved my afternoon^^

Comment: @El-Cortez
I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers."

Comment: Just done it, sorry, I though it was the up arrow that was doing the job. Thanks again ! ^^

Comment: @El-Cortez Up arrow is something like "Like" in Facebook and you can upvote all the answers while "Accepted"  means that this particular post answers your question/solve the problem described in question.